Symfony 7 Post login event listener not triggering
I have an event listener that I would like to run after Symfony's authentication flow completes that adds the current user's session ID to a Redis set.
I previously had this logic inside onAuthenticationSuccess but the problem I was having was that the session ID is changed by Symfony after AppAuthenticator->onAuthenticationSuccess() completes, and I was seeing the old/previous logged-out session ID going into the Redis set instead of the new/correct one.
I've set the event listener up as follows, however it looks like the PostLoginListener is not even being constructed (die() is not happening during login process).
PostLoginListener:
namespace App\EventListener;
...
class PostLoginListener
{
    ...
    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();    
        $this->redisService->sadd("sessions:userId:1000", [$session->getId()]);
        die("PostLoginListener has completed");// <---- FOR TESTING
    }
}

services.yaml config:
services:
    App\EventListener\PostLoginListener:
        arguments:
            $redisService: '@App\Services\RedisService'
            $security: '@security.helper'
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'kernel.response', method: 'onKernelResponse' }

The custom login flow is over here:
class AppAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator { 
    ...
    final public function onAuthenticationSuccess(...
    ...

Is there some config or something that's missing, as I can't seem to get this working?
Environment: PHP 8.3, Symfony 7.1.7, Latest Ubuntu, Latest Docker/Laradock.

I think this is mainly a timing issue, at kernel.response you may be "too early", could you try kernel.terminate instead as your event and see if that helps?

Did you set config parameter security.firewalls.main.logout.invalidate_session to false? If your session id not cleared after logout it means that your session has not been invalidated.
